# SQL - Select Single Record in one-to-many instances

Tags: sql

I am joining multiple tables, and one of the tables has timestamps associated with each entry. I'm using this particular table to identify a single timestamp.

The difficulty is, in a few instances, the logic repeats itself and I get duplicate records, only difference being the timestamp. What I'm looking for is a way to only return the earliest timestamp.

Example:

Query structure

```
Select Table1.ID, Table1.Timestamp, Table2.Text, Table3.text2

from Table3

left join table2
on Table2.id=Table3.id
left join table1
ON table2.id=table1.ID

where table1.text like '%From Group 1%'
```

Output Example Current

```
ID, Timestamp, Text, Text2

98, 2/4/2014, xxx, xxxx

99, 3/1/2014, xxxx, xxxx

99, 3/2/2014, xxx, xxxx <----Do not want 2nd Record
```

Ideal Output

```
ID, Timestamp, Text, Text2

98, 2/4/2014, xxx, xxxx

99, 3/1/2014, xxx, xxxx <---- Only 1 Record (earliest timestamp)
```

Comment: `Select Table1.ID, MIN(Table1.Timestamp) [TimeStamp], Table2.Text, Table3.text2 ....where table1.text like '%From Group 1%' GROUP BY Table1.ID, Table2.Text, Table3.text2`

Comment: are you using `LEFT JOIN`s for any particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is use the GROUP BY clause. You can't use DISTINCT, because you are returning multiple columns, so the DISTINCT clause will not return the expected values. You will also then need to add an ORDER BY statement so you can ensure you get the earliest date for each group (group referring to the collection of table1.Ids).

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Timestamp, Table2.Text, Table3.Text2
FROM Table3
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID = Table3.ID
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.ID = Table1.ID
WHERE Table1.Text LIKE '%From Group 1%'
GROUP BY Table1.ID // This will ensure only one appearance of each Table1 ID
ORDER BY Table1.Timestamp ASC // This will put the earliest timestamp first, so it will be the one appearance that is returned in the result set.
```

Let me know if you need me to explain either addition in more depth, as that is a pretty tricky query.

**EDIT**

After further thought, the DISTINCT clause would work here, because you don't want any duplicate values for any columns. All you would need to change then is to add the keyword DISTINCT after SELECT, and you can get rid of the GROUP BY statement. It would be a good idea to keep the ORDER BY statement, because you want to ensure the earliest timestamp is the one that appears.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ID, Table1.Timestamp, Table2.Text, Table3.Text2
FROM Table3
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID = Table3.ID
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.ID = Table1.ID
WHERE Table1.Text LIKE '%From Group 1%'
ORDER BY Table1.Timestamp ASC
```

Here's some more information on the [DISTINCT](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/distinct.php) clause if you were unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this problem? Just curious what your solution was, even if it was different than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL function DISTINCT in order to select diferent records:

```
Select Distinct Table1.ID, Table1.Timestamp, Table2.Text, Table3.text2

from Table3

left join table2
on Table2.id=Table3.id
left join table1
ON table2.id=table1.ID

where table1.text like '%From Group 1%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the timestamp you want to see, you can retrieve the first timestamp for each grouping of ID, Text, and Text2:

```
select
    Table1.ID,
    MIN(Table1.Timestamp) as TimeStamp,
    Table2.Text,
    Table3.Text2
from Table3
    left join Table2
        on Table2.ID=Table3.ID
    left join Table1
        on Table2.ID=Table1.ID
where Table1.Text like '%From Group 1%'
group by
    Table1.ID,
    Table2.Text,
    Table3.Text2
```